# Custom /catalogsearch/ filters

Tags: attributes, magento-1, filter, search, catalogsearch

Beforehand I have to tell: I'm a total n00b on Magento and what I need to know is more a "common practice" or "standard" about how is something achieved in Magento since I have to maintain (in record time) a Magento distribution (perhaps the previous developers created a dirty way to do what I will ask, but if I don't know the standard ways, I'll have even fewer chances to guess the dirty ones). For the explanation below, I don't expect you to hit the nail about it, but give me some guidance about it.

Let's see...

When I send a standard search query to /index.php/catalog search/result/?q=, I find products not present in many "states". By "states" I mean possible discrete values of the "Estado" attribute (a custom attribute for my Products).

As I can see, Products having certain values for "Estado" are not shown in the results (even when Visibility is set to include those products in the search results).

**Question**: Is there a place where I can set up a custom filter to use for my product list (as obtained from the search query) so I can keep only products in a certain state? What does Magento support, as standard, regarding that?

For "place" I mean an option in the Admin backend or, as the very last option, a chunk of code, event, callback, hook, interceptor, middleware, or whatever (I'm an n00b so I don't know the true term used in Magento) is used in these cases to intercept the query.

**Notes**: In app/design/frontend/caramel/template/catalog/product/list.phtml the first lines before iteration are:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<p>No encontraste lo que buscabas, <a href="<?php $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/index.php/pidenos?tipo=pidenos">p&iacute;denos</a> y lo buscamos por ti.</p>
<?php else: ?>
<!-- more code here ... -->
```

And as I can see, the filter is not applied here but it comes from somewhere else, and I want to know where does it come from (usually).

Comment: Another tumbleweed for me :(

Answer (score 0):

```
app/design/frontend/caramel/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

at this file Magento output result collection with all filters, sorting, pagination, etc.

```
app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer.php
method prepareProductCollection
```

Magento selects 'clear collection (method get product collection) and then applies catalog search filter (where condition) for this collection and route collection to layered navigation.

**you can use `<?php echo $_productCollection->getSelect() ?>` in template for output current sql query to database**